# Processing group aliases in a loop

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm having an issue getting a loop in a function to properly.  The goal is to compare the output of some JSON data to existing unified groups in Office 365, and if the group already exists, skip it, otherwise, create a new group.  The tricky part is that as part of function that creates the group, it prepends "gr-" to the group name.  Because the compare function is comparing the original JSON data without the prepended data to Office 365, the compare function has to have the logic to prepend "gr-" on the fly.  If there is a better way to accomplish this last piece, I am certainly open to suggestions.

Here is the latest version of the function.  There have been other variations, but none so far have worked.  There are no errors, but the code does not identify lists that definitely do exist.  I am using simple echo statements for the purpose of testing, the actual code will include the function to create a new group.

```
# Test variable that cycles through each .json file.
$jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\tmp\json" -Filter *.json |
             Get-Content -Raw

$allobjects = ForEach-Object {
    $jsonFiles | ConvertFrom-Json
}

$alreadyCreatedGroup = ForEach-Object {Get-UnifiedGroup | select alias}

# Determine if list already exists in Office 365
function checkForExistingGroup {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $InputObject
    )

    Process {
        if ("gr-$($InputObject.alias)" -like $alreadyCreatedGroup) {
            echo "Group exists"
        } else {
            echo "Group does not exist"
        }
    }
}

$allobjects | checkForExistingGroup
#$alreadyCreatedGroup | checkForExistingGroup
```

The above code always produces "Group does not exist" for each alias from the JSON data.

The individual variables appear to be outputting correctly:

```
PS> $alreadyCreatedGroup

Alias                     
-----                     
gr-jsonoffice365grouptest1
gr-jsonoffice365grouptest2
gr-jsonoffice365grouptest3


PS> $allobjects.alias

jsonoffice365grouptest3
jsonoffice365grouptest4
```

If I run the following on its own:

```
"gr-$($allobjects.alias)"
```

I get the following output:

```
gr-jsonoffice365grouptest3 jsonoffice365grouptest4
```

So on its own it appends the output from the JSON files, but I had hoped by using `$InputObject` in the function, this would resolve that issue.

Comment: Why are you wrapping commands in `ForEach-Object` that receive no input? Don't do that, it's completely pointless.

Comment: You're referring to $allobjects I'm guessing.  Thank you for calling that out, clearly I did not think that through.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I see the other one doesn't really need to exist either.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Well, a single group will never be `-like` a list of groups. You want to check if the list of groups *contains* the alias.

```
if ($alreadyCreatedGroup -contains "gr-$($InputObject.Alias)") {
    echo "Group exists"
} else {
    echo "Group does not exist"
}
```

In PowerShell v3 or newer you could also use the `-in` operator instead of the `-contains` operator, which feels more natural to most people:

```
if ("gr-$($InputObject.Alias)" -in $alreadyCreatedGroup) {
    echo "Group exists"
} else {
    echo "Group does not exist"
}
```

And I'd recommend to pass the group list to the function as a parameter rather than using a global variable:

```
function checkForExistingGroup {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
        [array]$ExistingGroups
    )

    ...
}
```

`"gr-$($allobjects.Alias)"` doesn't produce the result you expect, because the expression basically means: take the `Alias` properties of all elements in the array/collection `$allobjects`, concatenate their values with the `$OFS` character (output field separator), then insert the result after the substring "gr-". That doesn't affect your function, though, because the pipeline already unrolls the input array, so the function sees one input object at a time.